# Simple if statement on python interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, python-interactive, pythoninterpreter

Environment:

- Fedora 27 (GNU/Linux)
- terminal
- python3.6.3

I am having problems running this simple lines of code in the python interpreter, this is an only if statement or alone if statement.

```
n = 5
if n == 4:
    print('n=4')
print('done')
```

[image]

This must print the word "done", but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Python console in Pycharm works perfectly.

Comment: try `print 'done'`, maybe you are running it on an older version

Comment: No pal , I am aware of the version is Python 3.6.3

Comment: The brackets are irrelevant. In Python2 `print('done')` is `print ('done')` which is `print 'done'`.

Comment: The `...` is a hint from the interpreter that it expects you to be in an indented block.  Entering a non-indented statement in that context is an error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The interpreter gives you a line after blocks to leave blank for the interpreter to know your block is over (or to put an `else`, etc.). Putting something there makes it freak out. Just leave it that line blank and wait for the next `>>>` before your `print('done')`.

```
>>> n = 5
>>> if n == 4:
...    print('n=4')
...
>>> print('done')
done
```

Comment: well , That makes a lot of sense. My error was the last print , that in reality should be placed in the next _primary prompt_ (>>>).